# Installation error In magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3.5

i was intalling magento 2.3.5 which the lattest magento edition on my local system and encountered this strange error. when i dig a bit in to it, i found this solution which works well but i wana know why this happens. am sharing full lines code that has been changes in order to make it working as they have not explained it.
[image]

```
vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php file. at line 96

private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
  {
      $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
      $url = parse_url($filename);
      if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
          return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
```

Comment: XAMPP is no longer supported. Windows and MacOS are also not supported: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: please go back and reinstalled the magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question "why this happens".

As you can see that the code in `validateURLScheme()` checks if parsed `scheme` is one of above four `$allowed_schemes`. Since windows directory convention is different than linux, the function always returns false due to local windows files do not validates the condition.

To avoid this convention issue we add `!file_exists($filename)` condition. `!file_exists()` will satisfy `if` condition only when file is not found. Since file is found it will return true from `validateURLScheme()`. Which solves our problem.

As Kalvin mentioned in comment Magento v2.3 is not supported in Windows OS as per official doc. So we had to make such changes in core files.

Hope it answers your question.
Thanks

Comment: isn't these changes  in core file going to effect in future releases from magento??

Comment: Yes definitely it will. when you update your Magento version, the core files are replaced with new ones. So you have to redo them. To get rid of this the suggested approach would be to use VM stack.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: Please accept & upvote the answer if you like it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install Magento2.3.5 on Windows. It must be installed on Linux environment only.
If you want to run Magento on Windows, use VM tools e.g. Vagrant , Virtual box, Docker.
Many Magento features are supported under Linux only e.g. symlink inside pub/static css/js file

Comment: as am not familiar with linux do you have any best tutorials that will help me install magento 2 over linux system