# hi, I have installed Version 2.3.5-p1 Installation is incomplete

Tags: installation

I have installed  Version 2.3.5-p1 community edition

now I am getting the following error

Installation is incomplete.
Check the console log for errors before trying again.

Comment: Please check the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311897/error-incomplete-installation/311898#311898

Comment: can you share the error please

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**if above is your problem then you can follow this**

**vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php file. at line 96**

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
  {
      $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
      $url = parse_url($filename);
      if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
          return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
```

To understand this issue in detail please follow my question where lots of user has ans that why this issue has occurred

[Installation error In magento 2.3.5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316611/installation-error-in-magento-2-3-5/316620?noredirect=1#comment454018_316620)